# Unexpected import behaviour in Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, import, python-import

For context, I am using the `django-rules` package. This is accessed as follows:

```
import rules
```

This package requires a file to be created in each app directory called `rules.py` in order for the files to be auto-discovered.

The problem is that using `import rules` in the `rules.py` file causes the file to "import itself" rather than looking in the `site-packages`. All the relevant answers on SO point to using absolute imports instead - but this is only relevant on Python 2.7, not Python 3.5 (where absolute imports are now the default).

[image]

I suspect it might have something to do with the ordering of the directories in `sys.path` but I'm not sure how to fix the problem. Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Comment: Did you add `django_rules` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @wim I need to import the `rules` from the installed `site-packages` so I don't think relative imports are possible?

Comment: Why are you using `import rules`? Did you get this from the documentation?

Comment: @Monkpit Yep, it's there

Comment: @Monkpit To define a `@rules.predicate`

Comment: @Kieran you are correct, I deleted my comment when I realised this :)

Comment: for an extremely ugly workaround, you could `del sys.path[0]; sys.path.append('')` to reorder site-packages before local dir

Comment: @wim Thanks, I was considering that. I deploy to Heroku too so I was worried about having the same issue there!

Comment: I don't dare post this as an answer.  There must be a better way!

Comment: @wim Definitely! I'm going to raise it as a problem with the package developer too, I think this whole situation could be avoided with a better choice of name for the file.

Comment: I think this can only happen if your PYTHONPATH (probably set inside Django) points *into* the app directory where the app-related `rules.py` file lives. Normally, the app-related `rules.py` file could only be accessed through e.g. `from app import rules` or similar, and wouldn't clash with `site-packages/rules.py` (or `site-packages/rules/__init__.py`, whichever is relevant). So double check that your PYTHONPATH isn't overrreaching.

Comment: @Evert You're right! Each Django app is on my python path, but I certainly didn't put them there. Does Django or perhaps Pycharm do this?

Comment: @Evert I've fixed it. Pycharm was adding all the apps to my python path. Changing this behaviour fixed the problem! Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Actually, you should post the answer yourself, because it's a different issue: PyCharm needed tuning. My suggestions: 1/ update your question, including the fact that you're using PyCharm (I always start out with the assumption that people use the simplest text editor and a terminal), and 2/ let us know in your answer what you changed in PyCharm to solve your problem, but also why PyCharm had added all the apps to your PYTHONPATH (is that the default? If so, bad, bad PyCharm).

Comment: @Evert Thanks for your guidance, I have done what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was the result of several configuration issues.

- I had marked all of my apps as source folders in Pycharm.
- I had also selected to "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" in my run configuration.

As a consequence, it was possible to refer to `rules.py` as simply `rules`, rather than `appname.rules`. This caused the unexpected behaviour.

To resolve the issue I unmarked my apps as source folders and unticked the "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" setting.